# Как сделать что бы приложение на xamarin forms работало с заблокированным экраном?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Как сделать что бы приложение на xamarin forms работало с заблокированным экраном ?
делаю плеер нужно чтобы он играл и фоновом режиме

Comment: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#important

Comment: мне нужно для андроида

Answer (score 0):

Android: в классе MainActivity в методе OnCreate добавить Window.SetFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn, Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.KeepScreenOn);
В том же классе MainActivity

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    if (!IsFinishing)
    {
        // Приостановите звуковое воспроизведение, если не завершается активность.
        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send(this, "PauseMusic");
    }
}
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();
    // Возобновите звуковое воспроизведение после возобновления активности.
    Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send(this, "ResumeMusic");
}
```

Проверьте, что ваше приложение подписано на сообщения "PauseMusic" и "ResumeMusic" в главной странице (или в месте управления музыкой). При получении сообщения "PauseMusic", приостановите воспроизведение музыки, а при получении сообщения "ResumeMusic" возобновите его.

IOS: в классе AppDelegate в методе FinishedLaunching добавить UIApplication.SharedApplication.IdleTimerDisabled = true;

UWP: в файле App.xaml.cs в методе OnLaunched, перед вызовом rootFrame.Navigate добавить Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest keepScreenOnRequest = new Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest();
keepScreenOnRequest.RequestActive();